# SVN changes to trunk when working copy is pointing to a branch

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

I have set up an SVN repository that currently has the stable code in trunk and a branch on which new development is happening.

I would like to fix bugs on trunk and have the people working on the branch pick up bug fixes by merging from trunk on a regular basis.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to access the trunk version from Eclipse when I need to fix bugs, then access the branch when I do new development.

The only thing I can think of is using the SVN Switch utility to swap between trunk and branch.  But, this seems very clunky.  I tried switching without committing some changes I made to one of the files, and the file was then in a conflicted state.  This doesn't seem like the right way to me.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have **not** access trunk-version from Eclipse, because if you want to have sync-merge from trunk to branch you have to have Working Copy of branch, and `^/trunk` will be referenced only on merge (which is Eclipse-specific interface)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to use switch.  Before beginning work you should do switch to make sure you are on the branch where you want the changes to go when you commit.  If you have local changes, it is OK, but when you switch it is just like doing an update.  You can get conflicts if SVN needs to make updates to the files you have local modification in.

If you do not have any local modifications or unversioned files, then switch will not create conflicts.